# Tarantool WAL vs Redis AOF

Tags: tarantool

Redis with the `AOF` (append only file) parameter enabled can only lose a second of data. I know that Tarantool has `wal_move='write'` by default, as this mode provides data persistence for `vinyl` and `memtx`, and in what case can this result in data loss that cannot be restored?

The second part of the question:
what `wal_mode` setting do you recommend `none/write/fsync` for `vinyl` and `memtx` in particular?

I would like to get a constructive answer because a similar question was asked earlier but raised even more questions and he didn't give a clear answer:
[Difference between Redis AOF and Tarantool WAL log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939756/difference-between-redis-aof-and-tarantool-wal-log)

Answer (score 1):

Wal-mode `write`' may lose not more that 1 record (in case of hard server reboot); wal-mode `fsync` never loses data.

You may refer to tarantool documentation here: https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/1.10/reference/configuration/#confval-wal_mode

It implies that for `write` mode every operation is not acknowledged to the client until `write` syscall succeeds, and for `fsync` mode it is not acknowledged until a subsequent `fsync` syscall succeeds.

Thus, `fsync` mode "never" loses data - as it is persisted on disk before replying to the client. `write` mode may lose data during system reboot - data which was accepted to OS buffer but not flushed to disk. On typical workloads we've encountered cases when a single operation was lost in such a case.